# saving entire Windows event log for auditing & preserve digital evidence

Tags: forensics, audit, legal, windows-10

As an admin one gets tasked with configuring  [**Microsoft Windows 10**] computers so that auditing is enabled and captures all events as required by some list that's already defined and handed down.

There are dozens of other things in Event Viewer that I would argue are very relevant in saving should such a time come that all this data needs to be handed over as *digital evidence*.  My 2 questions are

1. How can I save **everything** that the Windows Event Viewer has in it?  I am familiar with Application, Security, and System logs and saving those as 3 separate files.  But there is a ton of stuff under *Applications & Services* and under *Microsoft* not to mention under *McAfee* and other things;  I want to just save everything into one file, how can I do that?
2. Where the end goal is *preservation of digital evidence* that would later support *computer forensics* and other legal stuff am I on the right track in thinking that from a lowly admin perspective all that really needs to be done with Windows 10 is just save the entire Event Viewer?  I am thinking if everything is saved to a single .zip with a checksum (*chain of custody*) every so often that is the [good | better | best] way to go?  Then that gets handed off to the lawyers and whoever, and the lowly admin is then off the hook?

Is everything that's relevant simply under `C:\Windows\System32\winevt\logs` ?

Comment: #1 is more of a SuperUser question

Comment: As for #2, your goal isn't clear. "preserving digital evidence and forensics" is a statement of a quality requirement, not a goal. What are you hoping to accomplish?

Comment: The short answer to #2 is that there's no end to the amount of logging and auditing you can do.  You _could_ capture every packet ever sent and received by the machine.  If you want to do that is a question only you can answer.

Comment: reworded #2 for schroder.

Comment: I realize there will always be some mindset of *you didn't do enough logging/auditing*.  I am not looking for the bare minimum, I am looking for what is **reasonable** and **rationale**.  If I don't understand it, or see obvious flaws with the process, or the process horribly inefficient and wasteful then I want to correct it.